# Concatenate with strings and dots

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a number of string values (lookup keys) that are assembled as X.Y.Z where X and Y are hardcoded strings, and Y an individual value. I am trying to write a macro TEST(Y) that gives me X.Y.Z

Example:

```
TEST(hello) -> X.hello.Z
TEST(foo) -> X.foo.Z
```

All my attempts so far have either led to non-expanded values, or 'error: pasting "hello" and "." does not give a valid preprocessing token'. I've tried several layers of indirection, but I guess I'm not fully understanding how this works :-(

Comment: Please show some of your attempts. We can't clear up your misunderstanding if we don't see what you did wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you trying this? Using `##` won't work because `##` is used to create individual tokens.

```
#define TEST(a) X.a.Z
```

should do the trick.

**Edit**: Err this will create tokens for you, not strings. @paddy's answer is what you want if you're building strings.

Comment: Hahah yeah I looked at your answer and suddenly doubted mine.  I guess we have both bases covered.

Comment: I actually need both, so this is perfect :-) I'll go cry in a corner for a bit, having spent an hour on this when there is such a simple solution. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

You can only do this in macro if you are dealing with constants.  *ie* if the `hello` that you pass is actually the string you want, and not a variable containing a string.

```
#define TEST(s) ("X." #s ".Y")
```

Comment: I guess it's just a habit I have when I make macros - to absolutely avoid any strange behaviour that could result from odd uses of the macro.  In this case, they're probably not necessary.